# Azure SDK 2.6 instllation for VS 2013 -

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, sdk, access-denied

Am seeking support to fix an issue that is holding progress on starting with Azure. When installing Azure SDK 2.6  for VS 2013, am getting below errors. I am admin in my system. I have VS 2013 + SP4. OS is windows 7 enterprise, 32 bit.

*

1. [176C:0720][2015-05-05T14:35:35]i320: Registering bundle dependency
   provider:  {3701b856-cd55-4a77-b6bf-50b7d8d6642d}, version:
   2.6.30423.1601
2. [176C:0720][2015-05-05T14:35:35]e000: Error 0x80070005: Failed to
   write run key value.
3. [176C:0720][2015-05-05T14:35:35]e000: Error 0x80070005: Failed to
   update resume mode.
4. [176C:0720][2015-05-05T14:35:35]e000: Error 0x80070005: Failed to
   begin registration session.
5. [01A4:1488][2015-05-05T14:35:35]e000: Error 0x80070005: Failed to
   begin registration session in per-machine process.
6. [01A4:1488][2015-05-05T14:35:35]e000: Error 0x80070005: Failed to
   register bundle.

*

Finally the installer says:

**
 **- Microsoft Azure 2.6 for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 . This product did not install successfully.**

The following products were successfuly installed:

- Microsft Azure Storage emulator -4.0
- Microsft Azure Storage Tools - v3.1.0
- Microsft Azure Authoring Tools - 2.6
- Microsft Azure Emulator -2.6
- Microsft Hive ODBC dRIVER 32bit
- Microsft Azure HDInsight Tools for Visual Studio 2013
- Microsft Azure Libraries for .net - 2.6
- Microsft ASP.Net and Web Tools 2013.4 for Visual Studio 2013 - Base locale
- Microsft Azure Mobile App SDK V1.0
  **

Comment: Tried installing in safe mode? What else have you tried?

Comment: Yes. not working either.

Ran as exe at first. then in safe mode.

Comment: Any idea on where to proceed next. This has been for 1 week now.

System is a new O/S.FORMATTED WIN 7 AND REINSTALLED

Comment: Couple of things I would check. Are you running it as an admin account? Silly I know but it does happen. Do you have any anti-virus which can be blocking it. Try disabling it

Comment: It is done. MCAFEE antivirus blocked  it.

Thanks Sam

Comment: No problem. I will put it as an answer so others can see easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best thing to try is to look to see if any anti virus is blocking it. Try disabling the anti virus and then see if that works.